# Usage of Number.MIN_VALUE

Tags: javascript

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE), MIN_VALUE is the closest value to 0 and any value smaller than it is considered 0.

However, I am trying to find a suitable example that explains its practical usage. MDN has used the following example -

```
if (num1 / num2 >= Number.MIN_VALUE) {
   func1();
} else {
   func2();
}
```

Here, why didn't we just check if `num1/num2 > 0`? Any good examples that may help clarify what I'm missing here would be appreciated.

Comment: That's probably as practical as it's going to get ;-)

Comment: @Jack - So using 0 for comparisons have no downsides to using Number.MIN_VALUE? I'm wondering though why this even exists if so. Its like the smallest possible positive value, but for what?

Comment: Yeah, as long as `Number.MIN_VALUE > 0` holds true :D

Comment: Hmm. Strange. I'll keep this question open for a while just to see if someone has another opinion. Thanks @Jack

Comment: It could be used to determine if a user input falls within the representable precision of Javascripts Number implementation (IEEE 754). A check could then be performed and an alert displayed or do some math using an alternative 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

**Practical use**

```
function largestInList(list) {

    var largest = Number.MIN_VALUE;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (largest <= list[i])
            largest = list[i];
    }

    return largest;
}

My Tests

it("Return the largest in a list", function() {

        expect(largestInList).toBeDefined();
        expect(largestInList([])).toEqual(Number.MIN_VALUE);
        expect(largestInList([-11])).toEqual(-11);
        expect(largestInList([-1, -3])).toEqual(-1);
        expect(largestInList([3, -1])).toEqual(3);
        expect(largestInList([3, -1, 8])).toEqual(8);
        expect(largestInList([4, 9, -1, 9, 8])).toEqual(9);
        expect(largestInList([3, 61, 8])).toEqual(61);
        expect(largestInList([3, 61, 8, 333, -1])).toEqual(333);

});
```